# AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'plotting'

Tags: python, bokeh

I am trying to generate a plot with bokeh in the following way:

```
import bokeh
p = bokeh.plotting.figure()
# ...
```

However, this results in an **error**:

```
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'plotting'
```

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to import `bokeh.plotting` directly.
The following way works:

```
import bokeh.plotting as bk
p = bk.figure()
```

Alternatively, you could import all plotting functions into the namespace directly and use it like this:

```
from bokeh.plotting import *
p = figure()
```

Comment: how come? why is that? normally bokeh.plotting should work, right?

Comment: This is expected behaviour. See also https://bokeh.pydata.org/en/latest/docs/user_guide/quickstart.html#userguide-quickstart